# ASP:NET MVC 5 Page Rendering Very Slow

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance

In my asp.net mvc 5 project, every page is rendering very slowly at 5-10 seconds. I've tried many solution to increase performance but I haven't found a solution:

- Web Optimization - all scripts and css files bundled
- Set to release mode
- I've tried ViewEngine clearing and setting one engine (Razor)
- I've tried urlCompression

(I haven't tried Etag)

On the Client side, I use ajax but my problem is slow page rendering.
This image shows a page rendered in 6,74 seconds (which is a typical time for other pages)

[image: [1]]

How can I increase performance for the page rendering, there is no problem on the server side. When I click any link to open a page, I am waiting approx 10 seconds.

Comment: That is the time it took the document to load from the server, not the time it needed to render on the client. What's happening server side?

Comment: Are you on localhost?

Comment: Problem cause by DevExpress. I was included to all devexpress script and js on every page. I changed with only necessary css and js , fixed it. Devex generating scripts at the backside this is expensive for client

Answer (score 0):

I not see all requests. But i fix same problem when i check all errors in request and set this setting (and publish/deploy).

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```